# .htaccess RedirectMatch getting 404 for example.com/choice/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a .htaccess redirect and I have it working, except for one of my cases.

When I have this rule:

```
RedirectMatch "^/choice$" "/choice/home.html"
```

The address: `www.example.com/choice` redirects to `www.example.com/choice/home.html`.

In contrast when I have this rule:

```
RedirectMatch "^/choice/$" "/choice/home.html"
```

And give enter the address: `www.example.com/choice/`
I get a 404.

I tried this modification of the rule:

```
RedirectMatch "^/choice\/$" "/choice/home.html"
```

Recycled the server, but I'm still getting  404.

This is the condition I have set:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/choice/*
```

My goal is to have it redirect to the same page whether the final / is present in the address or not.  Anyone have any insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` and `RewriteCond` have nothing to do with one another. The first is part of `mod_alias` and the second is part of `mod_rewrite` - these are two separate modules.

You can accomplish your redirect by using the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^choice/?$ /choice/home.html [R=302,L]
```

Change 302 to 301 to make the redirect permanent (cached).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, Will http vs https make any difference with this rule?

Comment: No difference - it'll retain whichever protocol is used for the initial request.